# Voltage and reactive power

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, power, electrical-engineering

Why are reactive power and voltage related? When the control system of a generator increases/decreases the current of the rotor, voltage and reactive power are increased/decreased.What is the relation between these two physics concepts? How comes and reactive power sustains voltage?

EDIT
This question is definetely not a duplicate.Every synchronous AC generator has a field excitation. That means that there is DC current on its turning rotor. How comes that when this current is increased the reactive power produced is increased as well as the voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is included in the explanations given in your other question here:

[What is reactive power?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242210/what-is-reactive-power/283793#283793)

Keep in mind that reactive power (KVAR) is a component of AC power, and is demanded by the load. Power generators are kind of automatically controlled by the load. When the load needs more KVAR, KVA increases (I think when you say "voltage", you mean "power").

Keep also in mind that when demand increases, it puts strain on the generators. Generators must be kept at a constant speed and excitation in order to produce the requiered KVA at 60 Hz; the increase in load introduces loss and reduces speed, in turn the generator will need more fuel and excitation to keep up.